# discord.py throws an error when using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, discord.py

I have a another process in discord.py. I want to run 2 bot class.

I tried

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot01 = Bot(command_prefix="!")
bot02 = Bot(command_prefix="2!")

def run_bot(bot, token):
    bot.run(token)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Process(target=run_bot, args=(bot, "bot01_token")).start()
    Process(target=run_bot, args=(bot, "bot02_token")).start()
```

but it throws: `EOFError: Ran out of input`

Comment: Can you post the **full** traceback? Not just the last line

Comment: What's the reason for wanting to run 2 bots from the same program?